# Pegar um dado do HTML para um SELECT em outro arquivo sem POST

Tags: php, mysql, select, condição

Bom dia pessoal, estou inciando minha vida em programação PHP e tô com um probleminha aqui. Eu tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form action="cadastro_pex.php" method="post">
<label>Período:
  <select name="periodo" id="periodo" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
        <option <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione...</option>
    <?php foreach ($ids_mes as $index => $id_mes) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $id_mes ?>"><?= $meses[$index] ?></option>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</label>
<input name="id_franqueado" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_franqueado?>" id="id_franqueado" />
```

Eu preciso que quando o usuário selecione a opção no dropdown seja feita uma verificação se existe na tabela categoria um registro que já exista o usuário E o mês, se existir uma linha onde já exista mesmo usuário e mês ai coloco um disable nos campos pra ele não responder mais. Fiz essa consulta assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria1 WHERE franqueados_id_franqueados = 'id_franqueado' AND periodo_id_periodo = 'periodo' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id_franqueado_consulta = $row["franqueados_id_franqueados"];
        $id_data_consulta = $row["periodo_id_periodo"];
    }
    if ($id_franqueado_consulta == '$_POST[id_franqueado]' && $id_data_consulta == '$_POST[id_periodo]') {
        echo "Teste";
    }
} 

mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Espero que possam me ajudar. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Quando o usuário seleciona uma opção no `select` é acionado o evento `onchange`, neste evento você deverá fazer a requisição para a página de verificação.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia !, tente dar uma pesquisada em Ajax, pois você esta tentando atualizar uma tela que depende de um dado salvo no banco que esta no servidor, para isso precisara fazer uma requisição simples em javascript.

Vou deixar um link para você dar uma lida sobre esse assunto, não é difícil e uma vez que você entender vai usar sempre !

http://www.devfuria.com.br/javascript/ajax-php-jquery/

Comment: Opa, valeu a dica man, vou dar uma olhada, acontece que eu preciso entregar isso dia 31, então não é um tempo muito viável pra eu aprender primeiro pra depois fazer algo... rsrs